# Configure XmlSerializer used for WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, xml-serialization

We got a docs from our client specifying that our WCF service we developing should return responses like this one:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hsdq="http://site.gov/21398">
        <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
      <inf:getCarsResponse xmlns:inf="inf">
               <hsdq:Message1/>
          <hsdq:Message2>
            <hsdq:ApplicationData>
            ...
            </hsdq:ApplicationData>
            <hsdq:ApplicationDocument/>
          </hsdq:Message2>
      </inf:getCarsResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But response generated by our service is slightly different:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <getCarsResponse xmlns="inf">
         <Message2 xmlns="http://site.gov/21398">
            <ApplicationData>
            ...
            </ApplicationData>
         </Message2>
      </getCarsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I know that I could fix missing of `ApplicationDocument` section and `Header` section. But how can I make my response be exact like provided?

I mean that I would like to configure `xmlserializer` to be possible:
1. Remove unnecessary `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces.
2. Rename envelope namespace `s` to `soapenv`.
3. `hsdq` namespace should be specified in root element and should be identified also by name not only by an url. (Compare in first response: `xmlns:hsdq="http://site.gov/21398"` and second response: `xmlns="http://site.gov/21398"`

I think I should use `IDispatchMessageFormatter` for that, but is seems too complicated for me that I couldn't use ut without any sample.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could do it. The namespace order of prefix should not matter to the server. You could write a custom encoder to swap namespaces but you should really check why the server rejects this, maybe it does not like something else.